# Importance to me or importance me

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, verbs, sentence-choice

Which one is correct?

> 1. I need a friend who will give importance to me.
> 2. I need a friend who will importance me.

I think the former is correct but the website “sentencechecker.com” says it's the other way around (it says that sentence 2 has no errors).

Can someone explain which one is correct?

The author misses a friend who used to understand her in every way possible and cared for her. But now she's far away. So the author is looking to befriend a person who would value her the way her best friend used to.

Answer (score 1):

*Neither* of your suggested sentences are correct. Your spelling/grammar checker is wrong on this occasion.

> <s>I need a friend who will give importance to me.
>
>   I need a friend who will importance me.</s>

We don't use "importance" (which is a *measure* of how important something/someone is) in this way.

Correct expressions would be:

> I need a friend *who is important* to me.

(meaning that *you* value *them*)

> I need a friend who considers me to be important.

(meaning that *they* value *you*)

If you really want to use the word "importance", you could say:

> I need a friend who knows my importance.

However, this carries a meaning of *self-importance*, because it sounds like *you* are valuing your own importance. For that reason, it is unlikely to be what you mean to say.

Comment: There’s also the possibility that someone is looking to befriend a person that is “important” enough to make their friends more notable. We really need to better understand what the author is trying to express.